# Cannot bind vue store to state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

When trying to use Vuex I get the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"`

Here's my code:

`src/main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

import store from './Store';

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    store: Vuex.Store(store)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`src/App.vue`

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <p v-for="todo in todos">{{ todo.body }}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    computed: {
        todos() {
            return this.$store.state.todos;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

`src/Store.js`

```
export default {
    state: {
        todos: [
            {body: "Go to store", done: false},
            {body: "Go to work", done: false},
            {body: "Go to bed", done: false},
            {body: "Go to bank", done: false},
            {body: "Go to school", done: false}
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of Vuex.Store(store).

Modify this block

```
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    store: Vuex.Store(store)
}).$mount('#app')
```

to

```
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    store: new Vuex.Store(store)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: I'm away from my dev machine for the weekend but I'd be surprised if this isn't the issue. Will test on Monday and let you know.

Comment: Let me know if it work. Thank for the upvote! Now I have a comment privilege.